# VirtualBox Access a guest from host and another guest

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I'm not sure if this is possible or not.  I'm doing some testing with Pfsense in a VM.  I have the WAN interface set to NAT in Virtualbox, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to setup the LAN interface so both my host and another guest can access it.

Ideally I would like the host and other guest to get an IP from the pfsense DHCP server.

Is this even possible?  It somewhat works with Host-Only but it doesn't give out IP address like I want it to.  Setting it to Internal Network works for multiple guests but not the host.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, the way I have seen it done is to configure Internal Network for the current guests and add another guest with appropriate configuration to act as a router between the internal network and your host.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is set up the first nic of the VM to be on a "bridged network" so it gets DHCP from my local network.  The second nic on the VM is on the "internal only" network, and uses a different subnet.  The VM acts as a router between the two networks, and I modify my routing table on the devices I want to connect to the other subnet.  Then I add more VMs on the internal only network - DHCP server, DNS server (fake top level domain, etc), sometimes mail servers, web servers, etc.